# Detail text for UITableViewCell getting truncated/exceeding device width

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a cell

```
   cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1
                                      reuseIdentifier:cellID];
   cell.textLabel.text = @"Date";
   cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self.dateFormatter someDate];
```

It works fine on Simulator but when running on device, I see **`detail text`** getting truncated.

I only see `"Dec 30 2014, 12:1"`

What is wrong with code above?

Comment: Try NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(cell.detailTextLabel.frame)); for both debugging (Simulator + Device) and place the output here with question.

Comment: from device and simulator {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}

Comment: try with another style UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle

Comment: Try cell.detailTextLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;

Comment: thanks for all responses. It was a mistake of my tableview larger than screenwidth. Can not accept any answer....

Answer (score 0):

Of course you get truncation, because the this type of cell looks like this:
[image]

You need to create your own custom cell and layout labels in storyboard or nib how you like...

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use subtitle style for your table view cell or you'll need to create your own custom cell in storyboard or xib.